# what happened when using qsort function?

Tags: c, qsort

I'm trying to sort the struct node by variable a, but the result turns out to be wrong.

My result:

```
{5, 4},  {6, 2},  {7, 3},  {4, 1},  {3, 7},  {1, 3},  {0, 0},
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int x;
    int y;
} n;

int num = 7;

int compare(const void *ele1, const void *ele2) {
    n *px, *py;
    px = (n *) ele1;
    py = (n *) ele2;
    return px->x < py->x;
}

int main() {
    n node[7] = {
    {4, 1},
    {6, 2},
    {1, 3},
    {5, 4},
    {7, 3},
    {3, 7}
    };
    int i;
    qsort(node, num, sizeof (node[0]), compare);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("{%d, %d},  ", node[i].x, node[i].y);
    return 0;
}
```

If I sort only six pairs of elements, then the result is:

```
{7, 3},  {6, 2},  {5, 4},  {4, 1},  {1, 3},  {0, 0},
```

which is correct, but when I tried with seven, it shows the results above.
Does anyone know why that happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of the comparison function should return a negative number, 0, or a positive number.  You are returning only 0 or 1.

Your comparison function should return something like this:

```
return px->x < py->x ? -1 : px->x == py->x ? 0 : 1;
```

or terser but a little more opaque:

```
return px->x - py->x;
```

See [qsort reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). It's technically a C++ reference page, but the explanation is good for C as well.

**ADDENDUM**

I forgot to explain what happened, sorry! Your comparison function does the following.

- Whenever `px->x < py->x`, your function returned 1, making it think the `px` tuple was *greater* than the `py` tuple, when in fact is what not.  (You probably wanted to return a negative value in this case.)
- Whenever `px->x >= py->x`, your function returned 0, making `qsort` think that the two values were *equal*, when in fact they may or may not have been.

So `qsort` is just blindly partitioning and swapping elements according to what your comparison function was telling it the order was.  As your function was giving back only "equal" (0) or "greater" (1), and never "less", the final result turned out to be rather scrambled.

Comment: `qsort` is a C standard function and the specification for the comparison function even fits this comment: "*The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison
function pointed to by compar, which is called with two arguments that point to the
objects being compared. The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or
greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to,
or greater than the second.*"